# looping over a list of calculated items and appending

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```py
def averageCandidateVotes(filename, column):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename)[column]
    x = data.mean()
    return x

def averageVotes(filename):
    candidates = ['brow', 'nade', 'harr', 'hage', 'buch', 'mcre', 'phil', 'moor']
    some_list = []
    for cand in candidates:
        some_list.append(averageCandidateVotes(filename, cand))
    return some_list
```

I have two functions where `averageCandidateVotes` returns the average vote a candidate recieved. The second function `averageVotes`: takes a csv file and is supposed to return a list of the means for each candidate in the candidates list. The issue is i'm only seeing one value being appended to 'some_list' instead of the values for each candidate. I'm I doing something wrong in the loop?

I'm expecting something like this as an output:

```py
[344.7164179104478, 108.32835820895522, 133.92537313432837,360.67164179104475, 109.22388059701493, 120.41791044776119, 126.91044776119404]
```

but I'm only getting

```py
[344.7164179104478]
```

What did I do wrong for the rest of the values not to append to the list?
full datasets can be found here: https://file.io/gFugYB8sOupl

Comment: The problem is that you have the return statement in the loop.  It will return as soon as it appends one item.  Just de-indent the `return some_list` line so it lines up with the `for` and you'll get everything.

Comment: As a side note, it's quite wasteful to read and translate the entire CSV file every time.  Just read that once, and pass the dataframe into the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pull your `return some_list` out one indentation level. Right now, it is part of your `for cand in candidates` loop, and so right after we get that candidate's average votes, we exit the function.

If you pull it out it'll run through all candidates *and then* exit the function.

```py
def averageVotes(filename):
  candidates = ['brow', 'nade', 'harr', 'hage', 'buch', 'mcre', 'phil', 'moor']
  some_list = []
  for cand in candidates:
    some_list.append(averageCandidateVotes(filename, cand))
  return some_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop stops on the first iteration because you return a value. Thus you just append the mean of the first and only value. Therefore you just get that value back. Edit to remove first sentence that was incorrect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are returning the list at the first check, it doesn't continue to iterate and just stops at the first.

this can be solved just by decreasing the indentation level.

```
def averageVotes(filename):
  candidates = ['brow', 'nade', 'harr', 'hage', 'buch', 'mcre', 'phil', 'moor']
  some_list = []
  for cand in candidates:
    some_list.append(averageCandidateVotes(filename, cand))
  return some_list # <- dropped indentation level
```

to improve you can use a `list comprehension`:

```
def averageVotes(filename):
  candidates = ['brow', 'nade', 'harr', 'hage', 'buch', 'mcre', 'phil', 'moor']
  return [averageCandidateVotes(filename,candidate) for candidate in candidates]
```